# Shortcut to toggle Bluetooth in Montery via blueutil shell script executed with AppleScript in BetterTouchTool

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator, monterey

I have set the Mission Control key in BetterTouchTool to execute an AppleScript and it worked fine before the update from Mojave to Montery which I just did

```
do shell script "../bluetoggle.sh"
```

content of file is

```
#!/bin/sh 

blueutil -p toggle
```

but can't execute in BetterTouchTool.. it says

[image]

Executing file from Terminal works flawless.

Executing another script (do shell script "../karaprof.sh") in BetterTouchTool with following content to switch profile in Karabiner also works perfectly

```
#!/bin/sh

pro0="e"
pro1="g"

cli='/Library/Application Support/org.pqrs/Karabiner-Elements/bin/karabiner_cli'

name=$("$cli" --show-current-profile-name)
if [ "$name" = $pro0 ]; then
"$cli" --select-profile $pro1
else
"$cli" --select-profile $pro0
fi
```

So my guess is I need to set permission for BetterTouchTool to execute scripts in Terminal, but how? I can't figure

Comment: Where does Automater come into play here?

Comment: ah sorry, my bad.. I sometimes automaticly (lel) think Automator runs in background when AppleScript is executed.. I of course meant BetterTouchTool

Comment: Is the script executable? Does it change anything if you add the full path to `blueutil`?

Comment: that was it... /usr/local/Cellar/blueutil/2.9.0/bin/blueutil -p toggle and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

set path to blueutil

```
/usr/local/Cellar/blueutil/2.9.0/bin/blueutil
```

and it worked like a charm

Comment: Isn‘t this binary linked to /usr/local/bin? Referencing the Cellar directly breaks each time the tool gets updated.

Comment: No it isn’t and this was my first thought too but last update was some years ago, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ thank you for your time and help tho!

Comment: `brew link blueutil` might fix this then (the version is still 2.9.0).